# Can I use Squash Flat's trip to trigger Spinning Throw?

Tags: pathfinder-1e, feats

[Squash Flat](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/feats/general-feats/squash-flat/) allows you to make a trip at the end of a bull rush which succeeds by 5 or more. [Spinning Throw](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/feats/combat-feats/spinning-throw-combat/) allows you to make a bull rush on a target which you have used a "successful unarmed trip combat maneuver", and then place them in any threatened square and push them from there.

Can I charge someone with a bull rush instead of an attack, use Squash Flat to trip them (assuming I don't use my weapon for the trip), and then use Spinning Throw to bring them back to me and push them somewhere else?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

### Yes, you can.

You can attempt to [Bull Rush](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/gamemastering/combat#TOC-Bull-Rush) the target of your charge, instead of making an attack. This bull rush allows you to activate your [Squash Flat](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/feats/general-feats/squash-flat/) feat:

> **Whenever you make a bull rush attack** and your check exceeds the target’s CMD by 5 or more, you can choose to expend one of the increments of 5 feet you would normally move the target back to instead attempt to trip the target as a part of your bull rush action.

Assuming you beat the target's CMD by 5 or more, then you automatically gain an **attempt** to [Trip](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/gamemastering/combat#TOC-Trip) your target. If this trip succeeds, and you are unarmed and your target is your size or smaller, then you immediately can spend a [Swift Action](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/gamemastering/combat#TOC-Swift-Actions) to activate the [Spinning Throw](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/feats/combat-feats/spinning-throw-combat/) feat:

> **On a successful unarmed trip combat maneuver** against an opponent your size or smaller, **you can spend a swift action to attempt a bull rush combat maneuver against that opponent**. If your bull rush succeeds, you can move that opponent to any unoccupied square you threaten, then push that opponent the number of 5-foot increments your successful bull rush allows. The target is then knocked prone. If the bull rush fails, you can use the Ki Throw feat as normal. If you also have the Improved Ki Throw feat, a successful bull rush allows you to push the opponent into a space secondary targets occupy. You resolve this effect as if you used the Improved Ki Throw feat to throw the opponent into that space.

Technically, you could even use this second bull rush to make another trip attempt with [Squash Flat](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/feats/general-feats/squash-flat/), but your target is already prone, so the maneuver would fail. But if the ability triggered a different maneuver, like disarm, it would be valid.

Just remember that to attempt a maneuver, **the target must be within your reach**. If you bull rush a target 10 feet away, how will you trip him if your reach is only 5 feet? You would have to find a way to [increase your reach](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/feats/combat-feats/lunge-combat-final/) first.

Comment: Neat, so it looks like both bull rushes would activate Merciless Rush and provoke Attacks of Opportunity from Greater Bull rush as well? (or should that be another question?)

Comment: The answer will follow the same logic as this one, the text says *"when you make a <maneuver> you can <do something>"*, so it will do what the text says it does, unless the action economy is involved (for Spinning Throw, it can only be used once per round).

Comment: Fair enough, I wasn't sure if "does spinning throw's movement count as a bull rush for all effects?" was different enough to warrant asking a new question.

Answer (score 0):

### No, you cannot.

Emphasis was being placed in the incorrect places to properly interpret how these abilities interact.

Squash Flat (added emphasis):

> Whenever you make a bull rush attack and your check exceeds the target’s CMD by 5 or more, you can choose to expend one of the increments of 5 feet you would normally move the target back to instead **attempt to trip the target *as a part of your bull rush action***. This does not provoke an attack of opportunity.

From Spinning Throw:

> On a **successful unarmed trip combat maneuver** against an opponent your size or smaller, you can spend a swift action to attempt a bull rush combat maneuver against that opponent.

You have not performed a Trip Combat Maneuver, instead you are tripping as *part* of your Bull Rush Combat Maneuver.

Comment: And how is this trip attempt resolved?

Comment: "*as a part of your bull rush action.*" Yes, you roll CMB for it, but its specifically *not* a trip combat maneuver (an action in its own right)

Comment: But if it isn't the trip combat maneuver, then there is no defined resolution. "Tripping" someone isn't defined by RAW and thus can't impose a condition unless it is specifically the Trip combat maneuver. In general, feats are inconsistent on using the "combat maneuver" wording, which leads me to believe it's usually implied (see: Greater Bull Rush; gives "+2 bonus on checks made to bull rush a foe. ... Whenever you bull rush an opponent...". If these don't apply to the combat maneuver, the whole feat is worthless).

Comment: No, you're over-specifying. Tripping and Bull Rushing *are* actions, not just the Trip and Bull Rush Combat Maneuver. Greater Bull Rush provides +2 any time you would Bull Rush something, not just when you use the Standard Action Bull Rush Combat Maneuver. When it says you can trip as 'part of an action' you are not doing 2 different actions.